# Should we make a "jealousy" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

We have a number of questions regarding dealing with jealous people. From [a search](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?q=jealous+is%3Aq) I found 7 open / 2 currently closed candidates:

- [How to deal with a jealous girlfriend?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/how-to-deal-with-a-jealous-girlfriend)
- [How to manage someone flirting with my partner at a party?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/240/how-to-manage-someone-flirting-with-my-partner-at-a-party)
- [How can I tell my wife that her fears and mistrust are hurting us?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11076/how-can-i-tell-my-wife-that-her-fears-and-mistrust-are-hurting-us)
- [How can I convince my partner to accept my best friend instead of wanting to break up?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/how-can-i-convince-my-partner-to-accept-my-best-friend-instead-of-wanting-to-bre)
- [Is it possible for my friend to resume communication with his unofficial sister without earning her husband's mistrust?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/is-it-possible-for-my-friend-to-resume-communication-with-his-unofficial-sister)
- [Girlfriend's sister's boyfriend talking excessively to my girlfriend](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8051/girlfriends-sisters-boyfriend-talking-excessively-to-my-girlfriend)
- [How to convince a girlfriend I have not been unfaithful](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/how-to-convince-a-girlfriend-i-have-not-been-unfaithful)
- (closed) [Is it unreasonable to feel uncomfortable when my Girlfriend frequently talks to her ex?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11640/is-it-unreasonable-to-feel-uncomfortable-when-my-girlfriend-frequently-talks-to)
- (closed) [How can I go out to lunch with a friend's partner with him not feeling betrayed?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8330/how-can-i-go-out-to-lunch-with-a-friends-partner-with-him-not-feeling-betrayed)

**Would it be appropriate to make a new tag, [jealousy](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jealousy) and add it to these questions?**

According to [the help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

As an example this would be like the existing tag [anger](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anger),

> To be used when question you are asking is dealing with anger of yours (in interpersonal context) or someone/something else.

So I think this would fit in with our current tagging schema, but I wanted to get meta input first before bumping all of these to the front page :)

Comment: Nice of you to ask first on meta, but a tag can be created by any user with a certain reputation level and applied by anyone to all relevant questions. Jealousy is such an archetypical interpersonal emotion that we should have created the tag a lot earlier! An important subject within IPS. It is very appropriate for classifying most of these cases.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Just trying to be polite ;) Plus I think it's nice to have examples on meta for future requests! Mostly, I don't know if it's ok to go ahead and mass-edit or if that would be annoying and I should space it out.. plus we had a small conversation in chat so I figured I should "make it official" here.

Comment: Maybe add the tag to 2 or 3 Q every day, so as not to bump up 20 old Q en masse  to the front page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there don't seem to be objections, I created the new tag [jealousy](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jealousy) and am adding it incrementally to the linked questions. I also wrote a [tag wiki and summary](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags/jealousy/info) - feel free to edit!

Comment: I wanted to do that... ;-)